# My hard disk suddenly active at 100% in Task Manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, task-manager

I was trying to install something on my computer with the installation source being disk D, but I noticed a slow installation process, so I went to Task Manager and I see the disk drive D running at 100% active, what s usually is the culprit for that?

Comment: Maybe do a hardware test of drive D:

Comment: How to do so? A software test for that? I am not an electronics guy

Comment: Look for the manufacturer of the Drive and see if the manufacturer has a hard drive App (or SSD App if SSD)

Comment: I recommend this type of question should be accompanied by some SMART info, like CrystalDiskInfo screenshot so we can see exact drive model + health status.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that there is nothing wrong with your drive (there probably isn't).

You can use the (Microsoft owned) [system internals process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what is pounding your drive.  Download it from the `learn.microsoft.com` link provided or search for it if you don't trust me ;)

1. Open the app `Procmon.exe` as an administrator.  (Right click-> Run as administrator)
2. Choose menu item `Filter` -> Then `Filter` again in the sub-menu.
3. In the first drop-down, change it to `Path`
4. In the second drop-down, change it to `contains`
5. In the third drop-down, add the text `D:\`
6. Ensure the fourth drop down says `include` (it is the default)
7. Click `[Add]`

Anything pounding the drive will appear in the window.

You can use this tool to figure out just about anything once you get the hang of the filters.

Answer (score 0):

Windows OS has some tasks that run automatically when new software or other files are added:

- Defender malware scanning
- Search Indexer maintenance.

In addition, Windows has Scheduled Tasks for Disk Optimization and other drive-intensive operations.

Use *Task Manager* to identify the culprits:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open *Task Manager*
- Go to the *Details* tab.
- Right-click on the column header row to *Select columns*.
- Select columns *I/O reads* and *I/O writes*, if not already chosen.
- Click on one of those column headers to sort by that field.

In the image below, the usual perpetrators are shown, e.g., [Client Server Runtime Process (csrss.exe)](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/csrssexe/), [Microsoft Malware Protection Engine (msmpeng.exe)](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-msmpeng-exe-why-is-it-of-high-cpu-disk-usage/) and [SearchApp.exe](https://www.minitool.com/news/searchapp-exe.html).

[image: I/O Reads and Writes]

Comment: Yes, this too will do the trick! :)  I love multiple ways of solving a problem.  Because "whatever it is" is POUNDING the drive, the reads and writes should point to the D:\ drive but there is no guarantee.  On the flip side, this is built in.  Nice answer.